# Как ограничить вывод символов в одной строке?

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно ограничить вывод. В каждой строке не более 40 символов. Если больше 40, то ставится многоточие. Как это сделать?

Comment: скажите по секрету: все заданные вами вопросы — это в рамках какого-то соревнования?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, похоже на лабу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, на университете задали сделать проект и дали срок неделю, так что здесь я ищу помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{37})....+$/\1.../'
```

Comment: ***Если** больше 40, **то** ставится многоточие*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но многоточие занимает 3 символа в этих 40? Т. е. я так понимаю, если строка длиной 40 символов или короче, то она остаётся неизменной, иначе ставится многоточие, которое тоже должно уместиться в 40 символов, не? Ну если нет, то надо 37 заменить на 40.

Comment: у вас в конце **каждой** строки будет `...`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а, всё, я понял, где накосячил. Ща попробую поправить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не каждой, а только тех, в которых есть хотя бы 37 символов. Остальные просто под регулярку не подойдут.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, исправил.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ещё исправил. При 40 просчитался.

Answer (score 1):

например, с помощью микро-программы на языке *awk*:

```
$ awk '{a=substr($0,1,40);b=substr($0,41);printf"%s",a;if(b){print"..."}else{print""}}' файл
```

построчно:

```
a = substr($0, 1, 40);
b = substr($0, 41);
printf "%s", a;
if (b)
  {print "..."}
else
  {print ""}
```

---

чтобы строка длиной больше 40 обрезалась до 37 символов, можно сделать так:

```
$ awk '{if(length($0)>40){printf"%s%s\n",substr($0,1,37),"..."}else{print$0}}' файл
```

Comment: Длина строк с многоточиями получается 43, что больше 40.

Comment: условием это не требуется, но я дописал и такой вариант.

Comment: Я так понимаю кусок условия про _"В каждой строке не более 40 символов"_ - если с многоточием получается 43, то это уже не каждая ведь?

Comment: `"%s%s\n"` - почему не просто `"%s...\n"`?

Comment: угу, можно и так сократить.